# Google API key and Heroku allowed referers

Tags: heroku, google-plus

I need to use Google Plus API in my app that is stored in Heroku. I got my Google API Key but there is no way to put the correct allowed referers.

My current allowed referers:

```
rocky-wave-5545.herokuapp.com/*
http://rocky-wave-5545.herokuapp.com/
rocky-wave-5545.herokuapp.com/*
*.rocky-wave-5545.herokuapp.com/*
rocky-wave-5545.herokuapp.com/
```

I have tried all of them but none works. The page that call this API is

```
http://rocky-wave-5545.herokuapp.com/start?var=1
```

I don't know if this matters.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you manage to find a solution. Hitting the same issue

Comment: Old question but issue is still actual. Did you find a solution?